# jQuery-validate: Using remote hides button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-validate

When I use the [remote method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) from the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and press the submit button, then the submit button name is not listed in the `$_POST` array. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here is a small example:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method="POST" id='mainForm'>
  <input type='email' name="email" value="test@test.com">
  <button name="superbutton">Press me</button>
</form>
```

When I press the `superbutton` I get the following output
[image]

When I add the jQuery Validation Plugin like this

```
 $("#mainForm").validate({
   rules: {
     email: {
       required: true,
       email: true
     }
   }
 });
```

I still get the same output. However, when I add the remote method:

```
 $("#mainForm").validate({
   rules: {
     email: {
       required: true,
       email: true,
       remote: {
        url: "test.php"
       }
     }
   }
 });
```

with *test.php*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode("true");
```

Then `superbutton` is no longer in the '$_POST` array.

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: When a form is submitted using Javascript instead of from the default action of clicking on a button, buttons are not included in the POST data.

Comment: @Barmar Oh. I think I missed something in my first sentence: "When I add the remote method **and then press submit**, then... I will update my question.

Comment: I realized that, I removed my earlier comment.

Comment: So when I use the remote method, then the form is submitted by Javascript, and when not using the remote method, the form is submitted normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using local validation methods, jquery-validate calls `event.preventDefault()` when validation fails, and otherwise returns normally to allow the normal form submission to occur.

This isn't possible with remote validation, because AJAX is asynchronous. It doesn't wait for the response, so it always prevents normal form submission. When the AJAX response is received, it uses Javascript `form.submit()` to submit the form.

When a form is submitted with Javascript, the button that triggered the original submission is not known by the browser, so it won't be included in the POST data.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now. Since I need to know which button was clicked, I use this ugly workaround:  `$('#mybutton').click(function(){
              $(this).before("<input type='hidden' name='mybutton' value='3'>");
          })`

Comment: I suggest you put the hidden input into the regular HTML, and then use `$("#whichbutton").val(3)`

Comment: There is also one other thing that makes this behavior harder to spot: If the remote function was used while typing in the field, then again the normal form submission occurs.

Comment: Right. It knows that it doesn't need to redo the validation.

Comment: I think I spend about 5h today with this problem and I almost lost my mind because sometimes the button name was shown and sometimes not. I am very happy that you could explain this to me! Thank you!!